# 64-Bit Opera 11 lags when open many tags or heavy website?

Tags: opera

Recently I made the transition from Firefox to Opera but now I'm unsure about my choice? Overall I'm very satisfied but recently I've experienced some glitches when I have many tabs open or when I load a heavy site like this one: http://extreme.pcgameshardware.de/luftkuehlung/110082-roundup-das-grosse-pcghx-luefter-roundup-2010-update-58x-120mm-140mm-luefter-im-test.html? Is this related to Opera at all or can it be a problem with my pc?

My version:

```
 Version         11.64 
 Build           1403 
 Plattform       Win32 
 Betriebssystem  Windows 7
```

Comment: What version of Opera are you running? I have 11.64 on Windows (32 bit) and that site works just fine (no glitches, no hangs). Try running a 32-bit version of Opera, maybe it will work better.

Comment: @Ove: I've added the requested information. I'm not sure what plattform Win32 means because I've Windows 64 and I thought those bits in the version number means 64 bit? Did you tried open more then one tab with this website I provide the link?

Comment: @David Open task manager on the processes tab. If there's a `*32` after `opera.exe`, then it's 32-bit.

Comment: @Bob: Then I have the 32-bit version.

Comment: Your question is not really answerable (define glitches?), but on Opera 11.51 (32-bit), Win7 x64, on that site you linked to, it's very smooth for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are no 64-bit versions of Opera 11 for Windows. Even though you have a 64-bit version of Windows 7, your Opera is 32-bit (it says so in about: Win32).

I also have Opera 11.64 32-bit running on Windows 7 64-bit. The page you linked to is very smooth for me. Try clearing Opera's cache (Opera menu->Settings->Delete private data). Then, close and re-open Opera and try again.

Opera 12 is planned to be the first version to be released as both 32 and 64-bit. It is in development right now, but you can grab the latest snapshot from [the Opera Desktop team blog](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/). You can install it beside your current Opera 11.64, and run both of them (they won't get their settings mixed up). If you want you can try the snapshot, maybe it will work better.